# Write the matrix representation of f with respect to B. That is, find: $F = [f]_B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have been introduced to transformations with respect to other bases and I'm getting a little confused on the problem for my homework.

My problem goes as follows:

Define a new function, $\ f : \Re^3 \rightarrow \Re^3$ which doubles $ \hat{b_1} $, and exchanges $ \hat{b_2} $ and $ \hat{b_3} $.

Write the matrix representation of f with respect to $B$. That is, find: $ F = [f]_B$.

Based on the example I have to work with, my professor seems to give me $B$ and also defines $[t]_B$, but for this problem, I am not given $[t]_B$.

So far, what I've done is this:

$
t(\hat{b_1}) = 2\hat{b_1}\\
t(\hat{b_2}) = \hat{b_3}\\
t(\hat{b_3}) = \hat{b_2}\\
$

Therefore, $F = [f]_B = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Am I going about this correctly? And how would this be done with respect to the Standard Basis?

Comment: What you've written for $[f]_B$ is correct. What does $t$ mean? And you can't do it with respect to the standard basis until you know how to express the basis $B$ in terms of the standard basis.

Comment: Can you clarify? Is $B=\{\hat{b_1},\hat{b_2},\hat{b_3}\}$?